# F# - can I apply Seq.map to System.DataSet.DataTableCollection?

Tags: linq, f#

Here's something that seems like it should work but doesn't:

```
let dataSet = new DataSet()
let dataTable1 = dataSet.Tables.Add("Bob")
let dataTable1 = dataSet.Tables.Add("Bilf")
let tableNames = Seq.map (fun (x:DataTable) -> x.TableName) dataSet.Tables
```

It gives the following error:

```
The type 'DataTableCollection' is not compatible with the type 'seq<DataTable>'
```

The same error persists when trying to cast it manually:

```
let tableNames = Seq.map (fun (x:DataTable) -> x.TableName) (seq<DataTable> dataSet.Tables)
```

Is there any way to perform F#-style sequence operations on a DataTableCollection, or is it necessary to manually convert the DataTableCollection to an F#-approved collection type first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`Seq.cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee370344(v=vs.120).aspx), which does exactly what you are looking for - converts from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<'t>`

```
dataSet.Tables
|> Seq.cast<DataTable>
|> Seq.map (fun x -> x.TableName)
```

Comment: @OverlordZurg I thought you were asking for a solution without having to cast at runtime. Of course if this is not the case cast is the first thing to do. I will delete my answer.